# Flex box doesn't stretch

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm currently doing some stuff with Flex Box and I'd like my flex box to stretch but I can't do it. Here is my codepen : https://codepen.io/chevalierv/pen/bGdBKyg

```css
  .FlexContainer {
      height: 65vh;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      align-items: stretch;
      align-content: stretch;
      justify-content: center;
      padding: 1em;
      background-color: red;
  }

.SecondChildContainer {
    align-self: flex-end;
    order: 2;
    flex: 1;
    flex-basis: 100%;
    background-color: green;
}

.FirstChildContainer {
    order: 1;
    flex-grow: 5;
    align-self: stretch;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="FlexContainer">
  <div class="FirstChildContainer">
    a
  </div>
  <div class="SecondChildContainer">
    a
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. What do you mean when you say 'I want my flexbox to stretch but I can't do it'?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply ;) On code pen, I would like that the blue box takes all the place left. There’s like a gap between the blue and the green box that I don’t want

Comment: I see what you meant! I have provided the solution in the answer below, if that helps you make sure you accept the answer so we can close the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have cleaned your css a little bit and made it work. See the jsfiddle below:

https://jsfiddle.net/gqptemhu/

Basically, what your flex container needs is

```
.FlexContainer {
      height: 65vh;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
  }
```

so it knows to stack the items vertically.

And you use

```
 flex: 0 1;
 flex: 1 0;
```

On the items inside of the flex container, to tell which item will grow, and which one will shrink. The first number corresponds to flex-grow, and the second to flex-shrink. They are both relative numbers which tell which percentage of space the items will grow/shrink to.

You can read more about flexbox and how to use it on the link below:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/